# Eclipse Luna takes a long time saving an xml file :(

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

About a month ago I went from Windows to a MacBook Pro. 
Same Eclipse version, (almost) same settings, but it frustrates me that saving an xml file takes about 10s :(... Even if I just delete/add a space char.

I have a lot of files, about 10 projects opens in Eclipse but my old Windows box with an old quad core (not even an i7) had no problems with this.

I know this is a knows problem in Eclipse and I had it in the past as well, but it was solved after a few upgrades in the past.

Currently I run on the latests Luna version, with up2date plugins, tried a lot of possible solution, most from SO, but still not solved. Please some help.

I am using EE Eclipse to mainly develop java web apps and use the following plugins: AspectJ (with Xref), EGit, JGit, CheckStyle, Maven, TestNG.
All files are stored as UTF-8

Editing the xml file is slow in both the text and the xml editor.
It concerns xml files that are located in a java package (in the /src/main/java/ folder).

The strange thing is that Editing an xml file in a project-root subfolder isn't slow, like:  project-root/test-output/bla.xml (works well in both the text and xml editor)... weird...
Both files (the slow and fast save one) are part of version control and used by Git.

In case I copy the slow file to the folder project-root/test-output/, it's also saved fast :(

Renaming the slow file such that it has the "txt" extension and editing with the text editor has not effect.

I thought it is caused by some builder that works only on the java source folder...
The project has a Java and Maven builder. Disabling them has no effect.

The Eclipse log file doesn't contain any relevant exception. It contains some key-binding exceptions and resource tree locked modifications, but these exceptions are old.

What I tried (what I can remember):
+ Disabled all validation (especially the xml validation), for all projects.
+ Ensure all latest updates are installed of all plugins, including the EGit plugin.
+ Disabled Checkstyle.
+ ...

Any ideas as I am getting a bit frustrated about this?

Comment: Are you using the eclipse's maven integration? Please post the exceptions from `workspace/.metadata/*.log`.

Comment: Just added the log info: no exceptions concerning this issue present.

Answer (score 1):

A poor-man's solution may be in

1. switch to a empty workspace (`workspace2` in example)
2. create a new pde-plugin-project (`mytestplugin` in example)
3. debug the `mytestplugin` means you debug a instance of eclipse too, so use the workspace you usually work with in the debugging-second-eclipse.
4. Now: save the xml-file in the debugging-second-eclipse with the workspace you usually work with, quick jump to the first eclipse and press "pause" to stop the second-eclipse.
5. inspect the compleate debug-stacktrace-thread-tree in the debug view (please post the image as a comment here).

Regards

Comment: How to start the eclipse app from the plugin project with the correct workspace ? I tried to configure it in the run config, but can't get it to start with my wrk space.

Comment: That was the first thing I did but it shows an error popup, saying: "Unable to relaunch the platform because the eclipse.vm" property has not been set. What I did: I am in the new workspace with the plugin project and start the plugin project as an eclipse app that will start a new eclipse app. Then I try to switch the workspace...

Comment: BTW: If I add the system prop "-Declipse.vm=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" to the debug launch config, I can switch, but it will kill the started eclipse app and in the eclipse console it says: "***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions."

Comment: This is a different Problem that neither can be fixed by this answer nor is part oft the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When Trying the solution of @Peter I noticed that the workspace I was using was located in the "eclipse.app" file like this:

/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/D:\Users\Ed\Develop\Projecten\EclipseWorkSpace/

No idea why/how this happened. However, I moved this workspace to a "normal" directory in my home folder, and how saving an xml file work normal, fast as expected...
No idea why having the workspace located in the eclipse.app made it slow, but it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse.ini.
Increase -Xms, -Xmx
This works for me.